# R - What is the purpose of .GAL lattice file?

Tags: r, autocorrelation

Could someone please explain to me what the purpose of a .GAL lattice file is?

I want to see if my data are spatially autocorrelated and I've been following [Bivand (2013)](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/vignettes/nb.pdf). I have loaded my polygon file of London postcodes. The response variable is broadband speed, and I have various independent variables including number of premises per postcode, number of broadband connections per postcode and whether superfast broadband has been enabled.

I'm not sure what I need to do to generate the .GAL lattice. I can't find an explanation anywhere. Here is Bivand's code:

```
> NY8 <- readShapeSpatial("NY8_utm18")
> NY_nb <- read.gal("NY_nb.gal", region.id = row.names(NY8))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be prudent to back up a step and explore the "spdep" package in more detail and not just try to recreate an analysis that you do not entirely understand. Bivand's code is irrelevant if we can not see the structure and intent of your analysis.

A .gal file is a weights matrix produced by the software GeoDa. The code provide is intended to demonstrate a function to read in an external weights matrix. You can generate your own spatial weights matrix, depending on desired contingency, using "poly2nb", "knearneigh" or "dnearneigh". What is not clear is what your response variable is. You cannot use "postal code" as the value you calculate the autocorrelation on because it is not a valid random field and has no numeric meaning. If you do not have an actual value (e.g., population) to use then you do not have an autocorrelation function to apply.

More detail and clarity is always appreciated and will provide you with a more useful answer.

Here is a quick example of an autocorrelation analysis, from one of my labs, using the sp meuse data. The "sdata" object is what would result from "readOGR" but in this case it is a point object and not polygon as I suspect yours would be. The overall analysis would however, be quite similar.

```
###################################################################################
# Set R environment, read data and coerce to spatial object
###################################################################################
require(sp)
require(spdep)
data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
    sdata <- meuse

# VARIABLE OF INTREST
Var="cadmium"  

# PLOT WITH OUTLIER REMOVED 
  spplot(sdata[sdata@data[,Var] < 17 ,], "cadmium", xlab="cadmium", 
         col.regions=topo.colors(50))

###################################################################################
# SPATIAL WEIGHTS MATRIX
###################################################################################
# CREATE NEIGHBORS MATRIX (ALL LINKAGES)
nm <- knn2nb(knearneigh(sdata))
  all.linked <- max(unlist(nbdists(nm, sdata)))
    nb <- dnearneigh(sdata, 0, all.linked)
      colW <- nb2listw(nb, style="W")

###################################################################################
# Moran's-I Global Autocorrelation
###################################################################################
moran(sdata@data[,Var], colW, length(nb), Szero(colW))
  moran.test(sdata@data[,Var], nb2listw(nb, style="W"))

###################################################################################
# Permutation test for Moran's-I 
###################################################################################
nsim <- 999

( Iperm <- moran.mc(sdata@data[,Var], listw=colW, nsim=nsim, 
                    alternative="greater") )
  mean(Iperm$res[1:nsim])
  var(Iperm$res[1:nsim])
  summary(Iperm$res[1:nsim])

plot(Iperm)
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thanks for your details response. The dependent variable is broadband speed per postcode (continuous), and the independent variables are number of premises per postcode (continuous), number of broadband connections per postcode (continuous), distance from the nearest telephone exchange (continuous), whether there is superfast next generation broadband enabled (binary) and the urban/rural classification of the postcode (quasi-ordinal/categorical). Do you have any advice? (I edited and added more explanation to my original question)

Comment: I did not realize that this was a regression question. This is a very large topic spanning spatial regression, conditional autoregressive models, mixed effect models and nonparametrics. In the simple case, you could try a simple linear model then apply a test for autocorrelated residuals "lm.morantest" or a Lagrange spatial dependency test "lm.LMtests".

Answer (score 1):

.GAL files were created as a means of specifying neighbor/contiguity relationships within the [GeoDa](http://geodacenter.asu.edu/projects/opengeoda) software package. They're text files containing lots of 0s and 1s, basically. You can read more details [here](http://geodacenter.asu.edu/node/402#new) and in the [GeoDa documentation](http://geodacenter.asu.edu/software/documentation).

It looks to me like the point of that Bivand article is to specify contiguity relationships in R without needing such a file.